# Git rebase to older commit

Tags: git

After picking up a project on and off for the last year, I've managed to put myself in a bit of a git bind. Here's what happened:

1. Starting Production version.  We'll call this `A`
2. Made some big feature changes that never got finished.  Accidentally committed this to the `master` branch.  Code never went into production.  We'll call this commit `B`.
3. A few months go by and I need to make some hotfixes on production.  Used "`git checkout A .`" to revert to the `A` commit, make my hotfix changes then commit on the master branch over the top of `B` as `C`.
4. Want to finish features from commit `B`.  Use "`git checkout B -b featureBranch`" to get a new branch with all of my unfinished features from commit `B`.  However, none of my hotfixes from `C` are included.

If I run a "`git rebase master`", all of my `C` commit fixes get applied but I lose my changes from commit `B`.

How do I bring forward my `C` commit changes without losing my `B` commits?

Comment: Please clarify with a chart.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be a cherry-pick ([`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)):

```
git checkout featureBranch
git cherry-pick C
```

That will work if, later, `featureBranch` will simply replace the current `master`.